# How do I add gesture to chart to using SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a line chart for a financial application. I want to add gesture to the chart but I couldn't succeed. I would be very happy if you could help me with this.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let stockData: [StockPriceData]
   
    var body: some View {
        
        ChartView
            .chartYScale(domain: stockData.map {$0.close}.min()!...stockData.map{$0.close}.max()!)
        
            .chartXAxis{
                AxisMarks(format: Date.FormatStyle(date:  .omitted, time: .shortened, timeZone: TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: -20)!))
            }
    }
    
    private var ChartView: some View {
        Chart {
            ForEach(stockData) {
                LineMark(x: .value("time", $0.timestamp),
                         y: .value("price", $0.close))
                    .foregroundStyle(Color.green)
                
                AreaMark(x: .value("time", $0.timestamp),
                         yStart: .value("Min", stockData.map{$0.close}.min()!),
                         yEnd: .value("Max", $0.close)
                ).foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient.init(colors: [Color.green, .clear]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)).opacity(0.1)
            }
            }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 10, height: 200)
        
        }
    }
```

I want to see close and timestamp values in this gesture.

My model and sample data are as follows:

```
struct StockPriceData: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var timestamp: Date
    var open: Double
    var high: Double
    var low: Double
    var close: Double
}

let stockData: [StockPriceData] = [
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695374220000), open: 0.86552, high: 0.86655, low: 0.8651, close: 0.86642),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695376800000), open: 0.86646, high: 0.86686, low: 0.86622, close: 0.86667),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695380400000), open: 0.86667, high: 0.86693, low: 0.86613, close: 0.86669),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695384000000), open: 0.86669, high: 0.86739, low: 0.86651, close: 0.86671),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695387600000), open: 0.8667, high: 0.86708, low: 0.86644, close: 0.86671),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695391200000), open: 0.86672, high: 0.86858, low: 0.86648, close: 0.86819),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695394800000), open: 0.86818, high: 0.86901, low: 0.8679, close: 0.86839),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695398400000), open: 0.86838, high: 0.86957, low: 0.86759, close: 0.8695),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695402000000), open: 0.86949, high: 0.86957, low: 0.86825, close: 0.86877),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695405600000), open: 0.86877, high: 0.86927, low: 0.86864, close: 0.86873),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695409200000), open: 0.86871, high: 0.86913, low: 0.86835, close: 0.86868),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695412800000), open: 0.86869, high: 0.86881, low: 0.868, close: 0.86809),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695416400000), open: 0.8681, high: 0.86856, low: 0.86802, close: 0.86831),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695420000000), open: 0.86829, high: 0.86841, low: 0.86796, close: 0.86826),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695596460000), open: 0.86686, high: 0.86808, low: 0.86653, close: 0.86781),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695600000000), open: 0.86771, high: 0.86825, low: 0.86761, close: 0.86811),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695603600000), open: 0.86811, high: 0.86842, low: 0.86773, close: 0.868),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695607200000), open: 0.86799, high: 0.86877, low: 0.86792, close: 0.86818),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695610800000), open: 0.86818, high: 0.86832, low: 0.86664, close: 0.86672),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695614400000), open: 0.86672, high: 0.8669, low: 0.86604, close: 0.86656),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695618000000), open: 0.86656, high: 0.86675, low: 0.8663, close: 0.86642),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695621600000), open: 0.86642, high: 0.86667, low: 0.86619, close: 0.86642),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval( 1695625200000), open: 0.86643, high: 0.86658, low: 0.86529, close: 0.86547),
    StockPriceData(timestamp: Date().addingTimeInterval(1695628800000), open: 0.86546, high: 0.8658, low: 0.86542, close: 0.86567)]
```

Comment: what kind of gesture?

Comment: I don't know its exact name, but when the user clicks on any part of the line chart, its value appears. I guess tap gesture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example copied from the [`ChartProxy` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/chartproxy) should get you started:

```
Chart(data) {
    LineMark(
        x: .value("date", $0.date),
        y: .value("price", $0.price)
    )
}
.chartOverlay { proxy in
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        // Convert the gesture location to the coordinate space of the plot area.
                        let origin = geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin
                        let location = CGPoint(
                            x: value.location.x - origin.x,
                            y: value.location.y - origin.y
                        )
                        // Get the x (date) and y (price) value from the location.
                        let (date, price) = proxy.value(at: location, as: (Date, Double).self)
                        print("Location: \(date), \(price)")
                    }
            )
    }
}
```

iOS 17 added a [`chartGesture` modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/chartgesture(_:)#) that might be useful but is (as of this writing) undocumented.